# Is there any GPU infomation to judge its quality in Unity?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, gpu

I need to set game quality at game start, to fit different Android devices.

I can use `SystemInfo.processorFrequency` to get CPU frequency, use `SystemInfo.processorCount` to get cpu count, then the quality of CPU can be roughly determined.

I can use `SystemInfo.systemMemorySize` to get memory size, then the quality of memory can be roughly determined.

But how to determine the quality of GPU?

I can get the name of GPU, but too many GPUs need to be set after that.